# Differences between best response, dominant strategy and Nash equilibrium

Tags: game-theory, nash-equilibrium, dominant-strategy

I can't seem to get the differences of these terms.

I watched [this video](https://youtu.be/VuDutyTs_r8?t=137) that has the differences of **best response** and **Nash equilibrium**:
[image: best response vs Nash equilibrium]

But then I heard about **dominant strategies** from another video and searched for differences to land at this [quiz question](https://quizlet.com/279580670/ch-13-econ-micro-flash-cards/#:%7E:text=Is%20a%E2%80%8B%20player%27s%20best,not%20always%20a%20dominant%20strategy.):

> Is a​ player's best response in a game the same as his dominant​ strategy?
> Not necessarily. If a player has a dominant​ strategy, then it is his best​ response; however, every best response is not always a dominant strategy.

Is there a table form that shows the differences of these 3 based on a specific player and what other players would do?

Answer (score 3):

Consider the following game between P1 (row player) and P2 (column player):

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}\hline
& L & R \\\hline
T& 1,1 & 2,0 \\\hline
B& 0,0 & 1,1 \\\hline
\end{array}

- $T$ is P1's dominant strategy
- $T$ is P1's best response to both of P2's strategies $L$ and $R$
- $L$ is P2's best response to P1's strategy $T$
- $R$ is P2's best response to P1's strategy $B$
- $(T,L)$ is the only Nash equilibrium

Generalizing from the above observations:

1. A strategy is dominant if and only if it is a best response to each of the other player's strategies, e.g. P1's $T$.
2. A strategy that is a best response to some but not all of the other player's strategies cannot be a dominant strategy, e.g. P2's $L$ and $R$.
3. A Nash equilibrium is a pair of mutually best responding strategies, e.g. $(T,L)$.