What is the difference between a nash equilibrium and a dominant strategy?
This is my understanding, please confirm if the following explanations are correct:
Nash equilibrium is where if the other player plays 'a', then 'x' is always best, not 'y'. But if the other player plays 'b', then 'y' is always best, not 'x'.
Dominant strategy is where even if the other player plays 'a' or 'b', 'x' is always best and not 'y'.
Is this correct?
Thanks

Does this answer your question: https://economics.stackexchange.com/a/43265/42?

@HerrK. Yes it does, thanks
