What is the difference between ∂ and d notation in the change in utility formula?
I'm a little confused with partial derivatives and total derivatives and their notation.
Given:
u(z,y) = y(z-20)^2
Change in u is then given by the following:
∂u = ∂u/∂z dz + ∂u/∂y dy
My questions:

Why is the change in u denoted as ∂u and not du? I understand that ∂u is the partial derivative of u with respect to some variable and du is the total derivative, in the case aren't we finding the total derivative from the sum of the partial derivatives?

Also, why is the dz and dy necessary? Doesn't ∂u/∂z in itself signify that u is being partially derived with respect to z? And the same with ∂u/∂y?




I think the $\partial u$ is a typo as it should be:
$$
du = \frac{\partial u}{\partial z}dz + \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} dy
$$
For the intuittion, consider a small change from $(z,y)$ to $(z + dz, y + dy)$.
The change in $u$ is from $u(z,y)$ to $u(z + dz, y + dy)$.
Then
$$
\begin{align*}
\underbrace{u(z + dz, y + dy)- u(z,y)}_{\approx du} &= \underbrace{\frac{u(z + dz, y + dy) - u(z, y + dy)}{dz}}_{\approx\frac{\partial u}{\partial z}} dz+ \underbrace{\frac{u(z, y + dy) - u(z,y)}{dy}}_{\approx \frac{\partial u}{\partial y}}{dy},\\
du &= \frac{\partial u(z,y)}{\partial z} dz + \frac{\partial u(z,y)}{\partial y} dy
\end{align*}
$$

The $\partial u/\partial z$ is indeed measures the marginal change in $u$ when $z$ increases by one unit. The $dz$ and $dy$ takes into account that $z$ may change more or less (relatively) compared to $y$. So although $dz$ and $dy$ are both (arbitrarily) small the relative change $dz/dy$ might be big. For more information, you might look up the concept of a directional derivative.



Thanks for the response, it cleared my doubts. I had another question which is game theory related. You could take a look at it, you'll probably be able to answer that one too. Here it is: https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/59678/what-is-the-difference-between-a-nash-equilibrium-and-a-dominant-strategy
